# Changing order in list in list

Tags: python, list

I have this list:

```
rnd1=[[group_a[0], group_b[-1]], [group_b[-2], group_a[1]], [group_a[2], group_b[-3]],
      [group_b[-4], group_a[3]], [group_a[4], group_b[-5]], [group_b[-6], group_a[5]],
      [group_a[6], group_b[-7]], [group_b[-8], group_a[7]], [group_a[8], group_b[-9]],
      [group_b[-10], group_a[9]]]
```

and I would like to swap order, so `group_a` and `group_b` swap places in app the lists in list.

The best I did is this:

```
rnd20 = [[rnd1[0][1], rnd1[0][0]], [rnd1[1][1], rnd1[1][0]], [rnd1[2][1], rnd1[2][0]],
         [rnd1[3][1], rnd1[3][0]], [rnd1[4][1], rnd1[4][0]], [rnd1[5][1], rnd1[5][0]], 
         [rnd1[6][1], rnd1[6][0]], [rnd1[7][1], rnd1[7][0]], [rnd1[8][1], rnd1[8][0]], 
         [rnd1[9][1], rnd1[9][0]]]
```

Is there easier way to do it?

It is for my premiership league simulation:

https://replit.com/@MariuszS2/premiership-test#main.py

Comment: (1) Research basic scheduling algorithms.  There is already Python code readily available to do your round-robin, home-and-home fixtures.
(2) As @Code-Apprentice already told, take a tutorial or two on list comprehensions.  Failing that, learn how to use basic loops.  Either will solve the problem without all of that typing, and with greater reliability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you should use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and invert the values in each list:

```
rnd1 = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
new = [x[::-1] for x in rnd1]  # -> [[2, 1], [4, 3], [6, 5]]
```